# list index out of range, cant see where?

Tags: python

Im currently working on this code, that supposed to remove words that starts with 'no' this is what i have written so far.

```
text='none none is here but none is coming here again'

def count_words(text):
    sent=text.split(" ")
    for i in range(len(sent)):
        if sent[i][0]=='n' and sent[i][1]=='o':
            sent.remove(sent[i])
              
    return sent
```

But when running i meet this error message:
IndexError: list index out of range.
Im not sure where im going out of range, anyone who can see that?

Comment: Every time you call `sent.remove`, the largest valid index decreases by one. But the range you are iterating over doesn't.

Comment: Are you trying to remove all "none" from the text, if so there are much better ways to do it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove items from a list while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating)

Answer (score 2):

after your remove the length is shorter. Typically, do range(len(sent)-1,-1,-1) to traverse from the end, or make a copy of the list to work with

Comment: Ahh that makes sense, hadnt thought about that! It works perfectly with -1,-1,-1. But when trying to make a copy its still suffers the same issue.. still same error message..  ive used placeholder=sent.copy()

Comment: print(' '.join(filter(lambda x: not x.startswith('no'), text.split())))

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, the index gets smaller every time you remove an element

You can solve that issue some way, but there's a somewhat more Pythonic approach to the problem, as seen below:

```
text='none none is here but none is coming here again'

def count_words(text):
    sent=text.split(" ")
    words = []
    for word in sent:
        if not word.startswith("no"):
            words.append(word)
            
    return ' '.join(words)

print(count_words(text))
```

Short primer if you're unfamiliar:

- Accumulate the words you want in a list: `words`
- Use the comparison method `String.startswith` to look for the relevant words
- If the word didn't start with 'no', then add it to your accumulator
- Finally join the message with the spaces we previously split by, using `String.join`

Comment: Ahhh thats a clever! and works perfectly!  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Thats because in each loop where condition "no" is valid, you shrink your `sent` array but loop is still referencing to original `sent` length.

You can check it by add `print(sent)` in for loop.

But you don;t have to do so much complicated logic to this kind of simple task.

```
sent = text.split(" ")
for word in sent:
    if len(word) >= 2 and word[0:2] == "no":
        sent.remove(word)
return " ".join(sent)
```

this code will do the same

Answer (score 1):

Your code is almost correct, I have done a minor change;

```
text = 'none none is here but none is coming here again'
def count_words(text):
    sent = text.split(" ") # ['none', 'none', 'is', 'here', 'but', 'none', 'is', 'coming', 'here', 'again']
    for chunk in sent:
        if chunk[0] == 'n' and chunk[1] == 'o': # if chunk.startswith('n')
            sent.remove(chunk)
    return sent
print(count_words(text))
    
['is', 'here', 'but', 'none', 'is', 'coming', 'here', 'again'] # is here but none is coming here again
```

Answer (score 0):

For Splitting if you are not sure about no of index data may have then we have an option to specify maximum number of delimiter split should consider, remaining data will be loaded over last element as :-  `string.split(separator,max)`

New code will be as given below

```
text = 'none none is here but none is coming here again'
def count_words(text):
    return [chunk for chunk in text.split(" ", 4) if not chunk.startswith("no")]
print(count_words(text))

Output : --> ['is', 'here', 'but none is coming here again']
```

We can tweak value of maximum element as per our requirements.